# Can't get the data from Object

Tags: react-native

I am confused with the data.

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('deviceuuid', (err, result) => {
  console.log('result =>', result);
  console.log('result.rawData =>', result.rawData);
})
```

console.log will show

[image]

Why `result.rawData` is undefined ?

Comment: Try `JSON.parse(result.rawData)`

Comment: let rawdata = await AsyncStorage.getItem('deviceuuid');

console.log(rawdata)

Comment: @hongdevelop It will return a Promise

Comment: @AnkushRishi Thank you very much, console.log(JSON.parse(result).rawData); will get the data now !

Comment: @Morton  If you run the code in my answer, you get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are getting an String. AsyncStorage.getItem() returns an String and is likely that that string were a json before.

To resolve this, parse the result to a json.

```
const resultJSON = JSON.parse(result);
console.log('result.rawData =>', resultJSON.rawData);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `JSON.parse(result.rawData)`

Answer (score 1):

The console shows that the data is in `JSON` format. But you can get the data without `Parse`.

```js
let rawdata = await AsyncStorage.getItem ( 'deviceuuid'); 
console.log (rawdata);
```